# Make objects move in Cairo

Tags: c, graphics, gtk, drawing, cairo

I need to use Cairo to make geometric formulas move through the screen.

How does one "move" objects (like circles) in Cairo? I did try `cairo_translate(cr, x, y)` function but it seems to change the referential for all the objects and I don't know how to produce de "movement". In other frameworks I would increment the `x` value and change the speed with an appropriate `clock()` function to control FPS's, then I would paint the drawing area background and draw the object with new coordinates.

But I don't know how to produce this with Cairo and all documentation I can find does not mention how this is done.

This is the code I have:

```
genRandVector(numOfBalls);

/* creates big ball */
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 5);
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
cairo_arc(cr, balls_MAP[0].x, balls_MAP[0].y, CONF.big_rad, 0, 2 * M_PI);

cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9);

cairo_fill(cr);

/* creates other balls */
int i;
cairo_close_path(cr);
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);

for(i = 1; i < numOfBalls; i++) {

    cairo_arc(cr, balls_MAP[i].x, balls_MAP[i].y, CONF.small_rad, 0, 2 * M_PI);
    cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);

    cairo_fill(cr);
    cairo_close_path(cr);
}
```

And my circles are still. I would like to make all of them move randomly. I just don't know how to make them "move".

Comment: cairo is not an animation framework; to "animate" things you need to queue a redraw of your drawing area at given time intervals and draw everything in the rect that changed over again. Also elements that you draw on cairo aren't "objects" per se; once you commit something (with `cairo_stroke()` and friends) it's on the canvas and can't be changed anymore.

Comment: "In other frameworks I would increment the x value and change the speed with an appropriate clock() function to control FPS's, then I would paint the drawing area background and draw the object with new coordinates." - okay, what happens if you do that with Cairo?

Comment: @immibis, I don't know how to do that in Cairo. I see no documentation to control programs clock, or where to put incremental functions within the loop, etc. I just don't find anything related to that topic.

Comment: @tvaz I thought Cairo only draws stuff. Looping, incrementing x values, and timing are not drawing stuff, so Cairo doesn't do them.

Comment: Yes, you have to queue all that through whatever you use to display your content. For GTK+ that would be the `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` series of functions combined with `g_timeout_add()` to run on a timer. There are also dedicated animation frameworks such as Clutter (that can be used with GTK+). You'll need to figure out what is best for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cairo doesn't animate things, and it doesn't have the concept of objects. Using cairo is more like using a paintbrush on a canvas: once you draw something onto the canvas, it's stuck there and you can't refer to it to change its properties at all, let alone move it around.

Therefore, to animate things drawn with cairo, you have to wipe the part of the canvas that's being animated and draw it again. How to do that depends on what toolkit you are using to display your graphics.

From the tags, I assume you are using GTK+. There are several methods of GtkWidget, such as `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` and `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()`, that will schedule a redraw of your widget. Call this in a `g_timeout_add()` handler to schedule your animation. You'll get a drawing signal (the same one you're using already) for the portion of the GtkWidget that you chose to redraw (which you can get from within the draw handler with `cairo_clip_extents()`). Since the relevant portion of the canvas will be blanked already when you enter the draw handler, you can just start drawing your next frame.

You may wish to consider using a dedicated animation framework instead if your needs are sufficiently complicated. Clutter is one specifically designed to be used with GTK+, but there are also others.